Relative acceleration in case of centripetal acceleration
Say there is a disc of radius $R$ which is rotating about its centre with an angular velocity $\omega$.
Now the acceleration of a point on the disc at $R/2$ distance is $-\frac{\omega^2R }{2} \hat{r}$ and the acceleration of a point on the disc at $R$ distance is $-\omega^2R \hat{r}$. So we get an relative acceleration of $-\frac{\omega^2R }{2} \hat{r}$. But definately the points don't come closer as it's a rigid body.
So what's wrong with my intuition ?

The distance between two points does not have to change for them to have a non-zero relative acceleration. One point can rotate about the other at a fixed distance. This is the case with the points at distance $R/2$ and $R$ from the centre of the disc. From the point of view of the point at $R/2$, the point at $R$ is rotating around it in a circle (note that we keep the direction of our axes fixed relative to the ground) so it has a non-zero relative acceleration.

Consider two stones of same mass. One is attached to end of a massless string of radius $R$ and other to the end of a massless string of radius $2R$. Both are collinear with the center and fling them in concentric circles with the same angular velocity $\omega$. You see that the inner stone has centripetal acceleration of $\omega^2 R$ and that of outer stone is $2\omega^2 R$. But since the angular velocity is same $\omega$, they travel same angle in same time given that there is no tangential acceleration.
Centripetal acceleration is a kind of unusual acceleration. It is concerned only with the change in direction of velocity rather  than its magnitude. The instantaneous change in direction of velocity in circular motion happens to be radially inward. It occurs all throughout the motion so it's direction is changing continuously because it's starting point is changing continuously over entire circle. Only its end point is constant which is the center.
It could have brought the outer stone and inner stone at a relative acceleration if it were to remain in same direction over some time. But since it's direction is only instantaneous, it is only the change is direction of velocity with magnitude remaining constant. Magnitude of $a$ will change only with change in $\omega$ then.
You also see that the outer stone has to travel a larger distance in a time interval than the inner stone so that the $\omega$ remain same. This is the reason the outer stone has to have a greater centripetal acceleration than inner stone. Taking a large number of points like that in a rigid body where $\omega$ is same for all points, you get the disk with this explanation.
